# Using #define for an if statement error

Tags: c++, if-statement, typename

I'm trying to create a readable function that will contain a large amount of repeating if statement using a section of my code below.

```
#define if_identifier(finder, to_find) if((finder = msg.find(to_find)) != std::string npos)

std::string Utility::Decode(const char* buffer, int &playerID) {
    std::string msg(buffer);
    size_t identifier;

    if_identifier(identifier, "P_ID:[") {

    }
}
```

Why does this code cause a `type name is not allowed` error?

Comment: Define a function instead of a macro, in the cases where you'd need that. But here, consider using a table of identifiers and a loop instead of multiple near-identical `if` statements. Think **DRY**: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because junk `std::string` is there.

Try changing `std::string npos` to `std::string::npos`.